# How to register an object (that isn't a view controller) as a Notification Center observer

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I know you can register a view controller as a Notification Center observer easily enough by adding `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(_:selector:name:object: )` in a view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method (with `self` as the first parameter). But how do you do this when instantiating an object that isn't a view controller? The problem I'm encountering is that when I put the `addObserver()` method in the `init()`, the `self` argument throws an error because the object hasn't been initialized yet. In a view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method, you don't run into this problem because by the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the view controller is already initialized.

Any tips? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to complete initialisation for properties first or call `super.init` if you're subclassing your class.

Below example will work:

```swift
class AClass {
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(handle),
                                               name: .init("NotificationName"),
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func handle() {}
    
}
```

or with an inheritance:

```swift
class BaseClass {}

class BClass: BaseClass {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(handle),
                                               name: .init("NotificationName"),
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func handle() {}
    
}
```

Comment: Oh how weird! So I just have to make sure the `addObserver` line is after setting any properties. Thanks!